# Возврат значения Ajax-запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как записать в переменную результат работы Ajax-запроса? Дело в том, что когда я выполняю операции с этим результатом в самой функции, которая выполняет запрос - этот результат доступен. Но когда я пишу в этой функции return respone - эта функция ничего не возвращает. Объясните, пожалуйста, как записать результат запроса в переменную или массив /объект, чтобы позже использовать его в другой функции?

Пример:

```
    //Ajax-запрос
$.getJSON(url, {}, function(response) {
  returnValue(response['def']); // нужный объект
});

//функция-обработчик
function returnValue(val) {
  alert(val); //есть результат
  console.log(val); //есть результат

  return val; //ничего не возвратит
}

//запускаю функцию
returnValue(); //ничего нет (даже undefined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь вы вызываете returnValue с передачей ей параметра который она возвращает.

```
 function(response) {
  returnValue(response['def']); // нужный объект
} 

//запускаю функцию
returnValue(); //ничего нет (даже undefined)
```

А здесь собственно без параметра, что она по вашему должна вернуть?
Вам нужно обработать ответ сервера в коллбеке, либо использовать механизм Promise.

Comment: А какой параметр ей передать, если она за пределами функции запроса?

Comment: Вы НЕ можете вернуть значение из асинхронной функции! Вы ДОЛЖНЫ обработать ответ в асинхронной функции ИЛИ использовать механизм промисов https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#промисификация

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду знать. Пожалуйста, напишите пример правильной обработки или исправьте мой.

Comment: Так у вас собственно все уже и написано вот в этой строке $.getJSON(url, {}, function(response) {
  returnValue(response['def']); // нужный объект
});  Вы просто должны понимать что это АСИНХРОННЫЙ код, вы не сможете получить доступ к какому-либо значению переменной пока не придет ответ от сервера. Поэтому весь код который описан вне функции колбэка не сможет получить доступ к переменной response никак, вам нужно работать с ним только тут.

Comment: Я это уже понял. Но что делать, когда нужно писать много кода, который взаимодействует с ответом сервера? Тогда эта функция приобретает нехороший вид.

Comment: Передавать ответ сервера в  другие функции в виде параметров, или строить цепочки промисов.